# How did Reyes infer that Dominic Toretto has people associated with him?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-and-furious-franchise, fast-x

In *Fast X* (2023), Reyes stands before a stack of money and addresses his son Dante. He wants
to ensure his legacy lives on and emphasizes the bond between father and son.
He confides that he has a job he can only trust with one man, his son.:

> Reyes: My most ruthless soldiers were watching our cash houses,
> and they let this **Dominic Toretto** burn what is mine.
>
> Dante: I'll kill Dominic Toretto. I'll kill **'em all**.

I know that “'em all” is a shortened form of “them all” and refers to
Dominic Toretto and possibly other people associated with him.
However, Reyes only mentions Dominic’s name here.

How did Reyes infer that Dominic Toretto has people associated with him?

Comment: Toretto is a leader (so name it first), and it would take more than just a person to perfom what they did (them all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There were a lot of witnesses

When Dom and his team were burning the money there were a lot of witnesses all of whom were left alive.

[image]

Not only that but the team weren't masked during the raid so identifying them would not have been that hard especially since they weren't trying to hide who they were.